# Generate Random Password which meets Active Directory Password Policy Complexity Requirements Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, active-directory, directoryservices

I am trying to setpassword with for forget password functionality.

```cs
public string SetPassWord(string userName, string randomPassword)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
    AdUser adUser = new AdUser();
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.SetPassword(randomPassword);
        result = "Success";
    }
    return result;
}
```

I need to generate the random password which meets the following complexity:

- Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters
- Be at least six characters in length
- Contain characters from three of the following four categories:

  - English uppercase characters (A through Z)
  - English lowercase characters (a through z)
  - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
  - Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)

Complexity requirements are enforced when passwords are changed or created.

Is there any inbuilt method which serves the above requirements? I have used below method to generate password randomely:

```cs
string randomPassword = Membership.GeneratePassword(8, 0).Replace('<','!').Replace('>', '#');
```

It throws the error when I am trying to set password. Appreciate if there is and validation or inbuilt method to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: I can't help you on the generate part, but I could give you a regex to validate it.

Comment: You could always randomly generate 1-3 items from each category, then randomly mix them up. Then run them through a validation regex to be sure. IMO, the validation regex is more difficult. And with 6 to 9 length would be un-crackable.

Comment: This `Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters` requires a separate regex or process. The rest can be validated with a single regex.

Comment: i agree . Please provide me the regex validation. Thanks

Comment: I have user below validation. Let me know if you have fast and better validation. Thanks for the idea. Appreciate the help.

bool isANameCharRepeats = Regex.Matches(uName, "(?=(..))")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                          .Any(y => randomPassword.IndexOf(y) != -1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this works for you. I originally wrote this for .Net Identity 2 but it should point you in the right direction. You can see how I'm using it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Eonasdan/CSharpBits/tree/master/CSharpBits/CSharpBits)

```
var validator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6,
    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
    RequireDigit = true,
    RequireLowercase = true,
    RequireUppercase = true
};

passwords.Add(GeneratePassword(validator));


private static string GeneratePassword(PasswordValidator passwordValidator)
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        var password = Membership.GeneratePassword(passwordValidator.RequiredLength, 0);
        if ((passwordValidator.RequireDigit && !password.Any(char.IsDigit)) || (passwordValidator.RequireLowercase && !password.Any(char.IsLower)) || (passwordValidator.RequireUppercase && !password.Any(char.IsUpper)))
            continue;

        if (!passwordValidator.RequireNonLetterOrDigit) password = Regex.Replace(password, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", m => rnd.Next(0, 10).ToString());
        return password;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doe not check the Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters validation

Comment: Surely you can write the logic for that

Comment: I have wrote the logic for the same and it seems working fine. Thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider's `ResetPassword()` method should do exactly what you're looking for. [MSDN - ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider - ResetPassword()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.resetpassword(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: From that page `The random password created by the ResetPassword method is not guaranteed to pass the regular expression in the PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property. `